# MySQL: выборка из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код, который берет данные из таблицы `table_prefix . files`. И в этой таблице есть ячейка `file_number`, мне нужно вывести ее значение ниже в условии,  но оно не выводится, если я напишу `{if $file_number > 2} <br /> {/if}`, но `{if $comment_id > 2} <br /> {/if}` всё отработает как надо, но нужно именно `$file_number`. Наверное, нужно в нижнем коде вытащить это значение.

```
if ($upload_link=='story')
         $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.file_fields AS `fields`, '' AS link_name 
                FROM " . table_prefix . "files a 
                LEFT JOIN " . table_prefix . "files b ON a.file_orig_id=b.file_id
                WHERE a.file_size='$upload_defsize' AND a.file_comment_id='{$this->_vars['comment_id']}' $hide_sql
                ORDER BY file_number";
    elseif ($upload_link=='orig')
         $sql = "SELECT a.*, b.file_fields AS `fields`, IF(LEFT(b.file_name,4)='http',b.file_name,CONCAT('$upload_directory/',b.file_name)) AS link_name 
                FROM " . table_prefix . "files a 
                LEFT JOIN " . table_prefix . "files b ON a.file_orig_id=b.file_id 
                WHERE a.file_size='$upload_defsize' AND a.file_comment_id='{$this->_vars['comment_id']}' $hide_sql
                ORDER BY file_number";
    else
         $sql = "SELECT a.*, c.file_fields AS `fields`, CONCAT('$upload_thdirectory/',b.file_name) AS link_name 
                FROM " . table_prefix . "files a 
                LEFT JOIN " . table_prefix . "files b ON a.file_orig_id=b.file_orig_id AND b.file_size='$upload_link' 
                LEFT JOIN " . table_prefix . "files c ON a.file_orig_id=c.file_id 
                WHERE a.file_size='$upload_defsize' AND a.file_comment_id='{$this->_vars['comment_id']}' $hide_sql
                ORDER BY file_number";
    $images = $db->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
```

Comment: @GreenMonster, я вот ничего не понял. Каким образом задача связана с mysql? Все запросы имеют `file_number` на выходе. И в самом деле - переделайте уже базу, переименовав атрибуты и убрав их префикс `file_`. В запросах и так понятно что они относятся к файлам (`files.name` вместо `files.file_name`).

Comment: @stic, странный вы, раз не поняли.
Там нужно делать еще один запрос с помощью LEFT JOIN. Например, "LEFT JOIN " . table_prefix . "files b/c/d/или еще что". У меня не получается правильно, вот это я испрашиваю - как правильно сделать запрос.

Comment: "переделайте уже базу, переименовав атрибуты"
Старые запросы мне тоже нужны.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что проблема не в mysql. 
Рискну предположить, что if $file_number > 2 "не выводится", потому что в $file_number число меньше либо равно 2.

Comment: Проводил много тестов. Были варианты, где число больше, либо равно 2.